# How to not submit in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have got a form, and many scripts do something in the `.on('submit'` function - that's why I must submit, but I must to do something with ajax and when form is submitting - I have got refresh page.

How can I stop submitting but save this submit event?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`. Also better if post your code!

Comment: stop: `event.preventDefault()` - save the submit event for future use (within the callback function): `$(this).doSomething()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the default behavior of a form by this way .

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});`
```

then you can hookup the same submit button to your ajax method .